# Public Data API for Token Security

Tags: spl-token, api, security, data

Does there exist a version of an API, like this

https://docs.gopluslabs.io/reference/tokensecurityusingget_1

which is not paywalled like birdeye.so API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From investigation, I have not been able to find a service that isn't paywalled and will allow you to directly check token security.

There are a few other options which aren't quite like what you're looking for, but may help:

1. [RugCheck](https://rugcheck.xyz/) - A frontend tool where you input a token address and it scans markets, and gives a risk analysis
2. [Shyft](https://blogs.shyft.to/tracking-token-activities-on-solana-in-real-time-e9a398e4b2c5) - a popular Solana API that could be used to replicate some of what you're looking for